# What does the dot mean in this line of code: 65.+rand(10)

Tags: ruby

I came across this line of code and could not understand the purposed of the dot. Could someone explain what the dot in `65 . + rand(10)` is doing and how this is different from `65 + rand(10)`?

For full context I saw this code within this 8 char random string generator:

```
(0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join => "QSILUSPP"
(0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join => "BJIIBQEE"
(0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join => "XORWVKDV"
```

Comment: If your question is specifically about the `65.+(...)` part, you should remove the rest of the line, since it's distracting from your actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice, that in original code there are 2 method calls - `+` and `chr`. I can show it by equivalent code:

```
65.send(:+, rand(10)).send(:chr) # is the equal to following line:
65.+(rand(10)).chr
```

This trick produces method chain, that allows to skip parentheses. With parentheses, `65.+(rand(10)).chr` could be written like this:

```
(65 + rand(10)).chr
```

Without this trick, `chr` will apply on `rand(10)` and the result string will try to be added to 65. It'll produce TypeError:

```
65+(rand(25)).chr
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Comment: (1) `65.+(...)` is not a trick, `67 + ...` is the trick (syntax sugar). (2) What you have there are not braces, they are parentheses. (3) You wrote "...apply [on] `rand(10)` ...", and you have `rand(25.1)` in the example. That is misleading.

Comment: Of course it's not a trick. But still it's unusual move for everyday programming. You need reason to call `.+` explicitly. In this case author used it for method chain. And that avoidance of everyday's programming practices is what I called "trick".

Answer (score 1):

It is not any different. As numbers are objects in Ruby, `+` is actually a method call and can therefore be using the dot syntax like any other method. The form you're used to seeing, `65 + rand(10)`, is "syntax sugar" and is equivalent to `65.+(rand(10))`.

Why anyone would write code using `.+`, I have no idea.

Comment: For the hell of it, here's the documentation for `+`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B